# Trying to drop NA rows when condition x is met in column 3

Tags: r, if-statement

Trying to Drop NA Rows which fulfill condition `df$e == 'a'`

```
c <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(NA,NA,NA,'f')
e <- c('e','a','e','a')
df <- tibble(c,b,e)


# A tibble: 4 x 3
      c b     e    
  <dbl> <lgl> <chr>
1     1 NA    e    
2     2 NA    a    
3     3 NA    e    
4     4 f     a
```

trying to get:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      c b     e    
  <dbl> <lgl> <chr>
1     1 NA    e       
3     3 NA    e  
4     4 f     a
```

I have tried variations of `df <- which(df$e == 'a' & is.na(df$b) == TRUE)` and `df %>% ifelse(df$e == 'a', drop_na('b'))` with no success.

Comment: google "subsetting data.frames R" and try a simply one `df[ df$e != "a", ]`

Comment: @Jimbou edited above for clarity. So my issue is that I need to filter both conditions, not just one. so when I try `df[df$e != 'a' & is.na(df$b) == TRUE,]` returns the same result as `df[df$e != 'a',]`

Comment: Solution `df[ !is.na(df$b) | (df$e != 'a'), ]`